# How to change how your Terminal app starts

Tags: terminal, customization

When I launch my `Terminal` app, it starts in a `Basic` mode. I'd like to do a few things:

1. Change default to "`Pro`"
2. Control how `Terminal` is started .. For example, i'd like to either use my keyboard or LaunchBar to bring first terminal as `Pro`, second as `Ocean` etc

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as number one, in Terminal preferences, select the settings tab, select "Pro", and click the default button.

Answer (score 0):

First make the two windows in the profiles you like using menu `Shell` -> `New Window`.  Then save them into a group with the menu `Window` -> `Save Windows as Group ...` and give the group a name.

Then in `Terminal` -> `Preferences`, go to the `General` tab and set the `On startup, open:` setting to your window group you have saved.